# How to access feature files in cucumber using Cypress latest version (10.2.20)

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have been working on Cypress's latest version (10.2.0) with BDD in cucumber. Everything's working fine just my feature files are not accessible. I have tried using SpecPattern as written in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Configuring-Folder-Structure) but no help.

The spec pattern line is as follows:

```
    specPattern: "/cypress/e2e/**/*.feature"
```

Also, My cucumber is imported and running fine

Cypress.config file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    on('file:preprocessor',cucumber())
    // implement node event listeners here
  },
```

Package.Json File:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor":{
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions" : false
  }
}
```

[Image showing there is no feature file in this directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUdCc.png)

[While my feature file is present in the same directory shown in the above picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwCUK.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your cypress-cucumber library.

This indicates you have an old version

```js
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
```

You should use this version

```js
// package.json

"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.3.0",
```

```js
// cypress.config.js

const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
```

Repo, instructions etc [Github](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor)

Comment: This problem is solved. 
but getting 1 more problem now.

It is:
```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/e2e/BankManagerLogin.feature 1:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `specPattern` to `"**/*.feature"`. This will search for `.feature` files throughout your project and not just a specific folder.

Comment: You are correct!